# Reading audio with Extended Audio File Services (ExtAudioFileRead)

Tags: objective-c, struct, core-audio

I am working on understanding Core Audio, or rather: [Extended Audio File Services](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/Reference/reference.html)

Here, I want to use `ExtAudioFileRead()` to read some audio data from a file.
This works fine as long as I use one single huge buffer to store my audio data (that is, one `AudioBuffer`). As soon as I use more than one `AudioBuffer`, `ExtAudioFileRead()` returns the error code `-50` ("error in parameter list"). As far as I can figure out, this means that one of the arguments of `ExtAudioFileRead()` is wrong. Probably the `audioBufferList`.

I can not use one huge buffer because then, `dataByteSize` would overflow its `UInt32`-integer range with huge files.

Here is the code to create the `audioBufferList`:

```
AudioBufferList *audioBufferList;
audioBufferList = malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList) + (numBuffers-1)*sizeof(AudioBuffer));
audioBufferList->mNumberBuffers = numBuffers;
for (int bufferIdx = 0; bufferIdx<numBuffers; bufferIdx++ ) {
    audioBufferList->mBuffers[bufferIdx].mNumberChannels = numChannels;
    audioBufferList->mBuffers[bufferIdx].mDataByteSize = dataByteSize;
    audioBufferList->mBuffers[bufferIdx].mData = malloc(dataByteSize);
}
```

And here is the working, but overflowing code:

```
UInt32 dataByteSize = fileLengthInFrames * bytesPerFrame; // this will overflow
AudioBufferList *audioBufferList = malloc(sizeof(audioBufferList));
audioBufferList->mNumberBuffers = 1;
audioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = numChannels;
audioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = dataByteSize;
audioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mData = malloc(dataByteSize);
```

And finally, the call of `ExtAudioFileRead()` (should work with both versions):

```
UInt32 numFrames = fileLengthInFrames;
error = ExtAudioFileRead(extAudioFileRef,
                         &numFrames,
                         audioBufferList);
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of the mNumberBuffers field. It's typically `1` for mono and interleaved stereo data. The only reason you would set it to something else is for multi-track data where each channel is in a separate data buffer.

If you want to read a part of a file, you would set dataByteSize of the buffer to a reasonable size, and when you read the file, tell the API only to give you that many bytes, and loop over it.

Comment: So, is there are usage scenario in which `mNumberBuffers` is something other than 1?

Comment: I am not sure if this argument is correct since in the aurioTouch2 sample, mNumberBuffers is set to be 2, I am wondering if someone know the reason.

Comment: And by the way if I want to simultaneously either encode or decode buffer, how I could do this work in separate thread

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem with mNumberBuffers > 1,,...
My work around involved creating my own internal buffer:

something like:

char buffer1[byteSize];
char buffer2[byteSize];
......

you could also use pointers to make things easier,..like:

buffer[index][byteSize];

then you would have to iterate through them manually and fill them up on the main thread to avoid glitches in audio.

ExtAudioFileRead will only fill buffer[0] in the AudioBufferList, you could then have that pointing to different manually allocated buffers as the audio plays.

hope this helps.

Comment: That was not exactly what I wanted to do, but it certainly helps if you want to fill several different buffers with different data. (My initial thought was that I could fill several buffers with consecutive chunks of data from the same file).

Answer (score 0):

mNumberBuffers == 2 when you're dealing with non-interleaved stereo.  It is the number of audio channels when not interleaved.

Answer (score -3):

Cocoa simply seems to not accept mNumberBuffers > 1. Which is a shame as it makes the whole structure useless. (I hope this is right...)

Comment: That's not true. I believe mNumberBuffers>1 is used for multi-channel audio. Just that the rest of the AudioBufferList structure has to make sense.